# Video play with intent and go back to my app

Tags: android, video, image

Is it possible to open video whit intent, watch it and then go back to my activity, or the better way will be to implement videview in my app? I`m asking this because videoview can open only some extensions, and this limit my chose for video formats. I need to display, one or two videos one after another and maybe a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried some thing like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("http://www.yourvideo.mp4"), "video/mp4"); 
view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

or

```
tostart = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
tostart.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(movieurl), "video/*");
startActivity(tostart);
```

Comment: Yes i have try ths for images, but for video, will be back to my activity after video end?